# How to load image in Picasso correctly

Tags: java, android, picasso

**Hi, i'm trying load images from url like this: [link](https://lectortmo.com/viewer/656f0c7d9478ae21cbd6b1060749b645/cascade)

As you can see, the images have different sizes. For example, the first image is 1920x1280 in size. The second image is 720x11523 in size and the last image is 720x5420 in size.

But, this in my application looks like this:

[image: The first image is cut off]
[image: The rest of the images are not centered]

```
1- The first image is cut off 
2- The rest of the images are not centered and do not occupy the entire width of the screen
```

In this [link](https://lectortmo.com/viewer/ce158a25318218217f3a4b76bafa9ba4/cascade)

As you can see, the images have different sizes. For example, the first image is 1702x1080 in size. The second image is 1170x1618 in size and the last image is 986x1238 in size.

In my application looks like this: same problems, images are cropped, not centered and do not occupy the entire width of the screen

This is my adapter layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/CardView.Light"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@color/blanco">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/blanco">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/ivPaginas"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

My adapter class:

```
public class TMOnlineLectorAdaptador extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TMOnlineLectorAdaptador.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<TMOLectorClase> tmoLectorClases;
    private Context context;

    public TMOnlineLectorAdaptador(ArrayList<TMOLectorClase> tmoItems, Context context) {
        this.tmoLectorClases = tmoItems;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public TMOnlineLectorAdaptador.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adaptador_lectortmo, parent, false);
        return new TMOnlineLectorAdaptador.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final TMOnlineLectorAdaptador.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        TMOLectorClase tmoLectorClase = this.tmoLectorClases.get(position);
        Picasso.get().load(tmoLectorClase.getImg()).into(holder.iv);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return tmoLectorClases.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        ImageView iv;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View view) {
            super(view);
            iv = view.findViewById(R.id.ivPaginas);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        }
    }

    public void setFilter(ArrayList<TMOLectorClase> newList) {
        tmoLectorClases = new ArrayList<>();
        tmoLectorClases.addAll(newList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void updateData(ArrayList<TMOLectorClase> items) {
        this.tmoLectorClases = items;
    }
}
```

My Activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activities.TMO.TMOnlineLector"
    android:background="@color/blanco"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvCapitulosSeleccion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My activity class:

```
private String url = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tmonline_lector);

    url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvCapitulosSeleccion);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    adapter = new TMOnlineLectorAdaptador(tmoLectorClases, TMOnlineLector.this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    Content content = new Content();
    content.execute();
}

private class Content extends AsyncTask<Void,Void, ArrayList<TMOLectorClase>> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<TMOLectorClase> items) {
        super.onPostExecute(items);
        //Actualizar información
        adapter.updateData(items);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<TMOLectorClase> doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        tmoLectorClases.clear();
        try {
            String nuevaUrl = Jsoup.connect(url).followRedirects(true).execute().url().toExternalForm();
            Log.d("Items", "Url: " + nuevaUrl);

            if(nuevaUrl.contains("/paginated")){
                nuevaUrl = nuevaUrl.replaceAll("/paginated", "/cascade");
                Log.d("items", "doInBackground: " + nuevaUrl);

                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(nuevaUrl).get();
                Log.d("Items", "Url: " + doc);

                Elements data = doc.select("div.img-container.text-center");
                for (Element e : data){
                    String imgUrl = "";
                    if(e.select("div.img-container.text-center").size() > 0)
                    imgUrl = e.select("img").get(0).attr("data-src");
                    Log.d("TAG", "doInBackground: " + imgUrl);
                    //String imgUrl = e.select("img").attr("data-src");
                    tmoLectorClases.add(new TMOLectorClase(imgUrl));
                }
            }else{
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(nuevaUrl).get();

                Elements data = doc.select("div.img-container.text-center");
                for (Element e : data){
                    String imgUrl = e.select("img").attr("data-src");
                    Log.d("items", "doInBackground: "+ imgUrl);
                    tmoLectorClases.add(new TMOLectorClase(imgUrl));
                }
            }
        }  catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return tmoLectorClases;
    }
}
```

How can I solve the mentioned problems?

Comment: i suggest you to use Glide because once your image load its store in cache and its dont take to load for showing image from url

Comment: Well, i try to use Glide but this no show nothing in my imageview @Amitpandey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Picasso's `fit()` function combined with a `centerCrop()` or `centerInside()`. You can read about these functions [here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/picasso-image-resizing-scaling-and-fit).

Try changing `onBindViewHolder` to the following:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final TMOnlineLectorAdaptador.ViewHolder holder, 
                                                                            int position) {
        TMOLectorClase tmoLectorClase = this.tmoLectorClases.get(position);
        Picasso.with(context)
               .load(tmoLectorClase.getImg())
               .fit()
               .centerCrop()
               .into(holder.iv);
}
```

Comment: `Cannot resolve method 'with' in 'Picasso'` ← in this line `Picasso.with(context)`

Comment: And, this not works for me. Nothing show in the imageview

Comment: Sorry, my bad. with(context) was replaced with get() in Picasso. Did you try adding scaleType to your image view? If not, try adding iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP); in the constructor for ViewHolder.

Comment: In the `layout` code from my adapter you can see that i'm using `scaleType="center"`

Comment: Okay, in the adapter layout try adding `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` and changing `scaleType` to `scaleType=fitCenter`.